# Hi, i am trying to implement GeoFencing , i have created one CoreLocationManager class and accessing same in WindowGroup, not getting callback

Tags: swift, swiftui, geofencing

i wanted callback for didEnterRegion and didExitRegion when user enters in location coordinates, as i am getting callback on location changes but not for geofence area, not sure why it is not working , Could someone pls helps in same.

```
 
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
 
class CoreLocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager?
    
    @Published var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
    var locations: [CoordinateModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            
        }
    }
    var locationCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    
    /// used to through the updates to corresponding Models, when there is changes occurs for the following properties
    var locationUpdateHandler: ((CLLocation) -> Void)?
    var authorizationStatusHandler: ((CLAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)?
    var geoFenchCompletion: (((String),(String)) -> Void)?
    
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAppStateChange), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setUpLocationManager()
        }
    }
    
    func setUpLocationManager() {
        if !isDeviceLocationEnabled() {
            //// Perfoem action to update user that device location is off
            /// This is device level permission access
            return
        }
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        addBackgroundFetching()
        
    }
    
    //MARK: GeoFench Area
    ////  as we have multiple coordinates which is used to notify user when her current location arrives / exit the lat long
    /// here we are creating circular region with containing all lat long
    func startMonitoring() {
        for location in locations {
            print(locations.count)
            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude,
                                                                         longitude: location.longitude),
                                          radius: 150, identifier: location.title)
            region.notifyOnEntry = true
            region.notifyOnExit = true
            print(region)
            locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
    }
    
    func addBackgroundFetching() {
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    }
}
 
//MARK: Location Manager Delegate
extension CoreLocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        print(location)
        currentLocation = location
        locationUpdateHandler?(currentLocation ?? CLLocation())
    }
    
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        
        authorizationStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
        authorizationStatusHandler?(locationManager?.authorizationStatus ?? .notDetermined)
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            // Handle the event that the user entered a nearby location
            print("Entered region: \(region.identifier)")
            geoFenchCompletion?(("entered"), (region.identifier))
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            // Handle the event that the user entered a nearby location
            print("Leaving region: \(region.identifier)")
            geoFenchCompletion?(("leaving"), (region.identifier))
        }
    }
}
 
// MARK: Location Permissions
extension CoreLocationManager {
    
    
    func isDeviceLocationEnabled() -> Bool {
        return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
    
    func isAppLocationDisabled() -> Bool {
        if locationManager?.authorizationStatus == .denied {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    @objc func handleAppStateChange() {
        ////  Intially when you launch app, user allow condition for location access, if user goes to setting application
        /// and update appplication location access, here we will get callback and perform action accordingly
        authorizationStatus = locationManager?.authorizationStatus ?? .notDetermined
        authorizationStatusHandler?(locationManager?.authorizationStatus ?? .notDetermined)
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}


WindowGroup :
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CoordinatorView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(Constants.NotificationNames.customerList))) { notification in
                    if let customerCoordinates = notification.userInfo?[Constants.NotificationNames.customerList] as? [CoordinateModel] {
                        let _ = print("==customerCoordinates==",customerCoordinates)
                        coreLocationManager = CoreLocationManager()
                        coreLocationManager?.locations = customerCoordinates
                        coreLocationManager?.startMonitoring()
                        
                        coreLocationManager?.geoFenchCompletion = { (geoFenchType, customerName) in
                            print(geoFenchType)
                            print(customerName)
                        }
                        
                        // Subscribe to CoreLocationManager's authorizationStatus updates
                        coreLocationManager?.authorizationStatusHandler = { status in
                            print(status.rawValue)
                            if status == .denied {
                                showAlert.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Geofence Event"), message: Text("alertMessage"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
        }
    }
```

I am getting callback at authorizationStatus Handler but not getting on geoFenchCompletion, stuck from long long time

Comment: Where/how are you storing `coreLocationManager`?

Comment: I am calling functions from CoreLocationManager  for triggering the enter and exit the geofence region and sending locations with lat and long to create geofence location, what are you asking about storing?

Comment: Somewhere, you have `var coreLocationManager` or `let coreLocationManager`, but you have not shown that. You should consider including a [mre]

Comment: Oh ok sorry my bad @state var coreLocationManager:CoreLocationManager?

Comment: You probably should be using `@StateObject` for an `ObservableObject`. Again, it would be nice to see a [mre]